# How do I select an ndb property with a string?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

With a data model like this

```
class M(ndb.Model):
    p1 = ndb.StringProperty()
    p2 = ndb.StringProperty() 
    p3 = ndb.StringProperty()
```

I'm trying to set the property values with a loop something like this

```
list = ["a","b","c", "d"]
newM = M( id = "1234" )
for p in ['p1','p2','p3']:
    newM[p] = choice(list)
newM.put()
```

But I get an error

> ERROR 'M' object does not support item assignment

Is there a way to do this without explicitly defining each property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

python has [setattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) which will do what you want. Inside your loop:

```
setattr(newM, p, choice(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

p1, p2, p3 are defined as attributes of the model, and models do not support setitem or getitem access (i.e the model does not behave like a dictionary).  As the other answer suggests using setattr, which will work.  However just occasionally that can cause a problem, depending on the type you are trying do the setattr with.  An other alternative is to use `_set_value` which looks like

```
for prop in M._properties.values():
    prop._set_value(newM,choice(list)
```

or if you only want specific properties rather than all.

```
clist= ["a","b","c", "d"]
newM = M( id = "1234" )
for p in ['p1','p2','p3']:
    M._properties[p]._set_value(newM,choice(clist))
newM.put()
```

Something else to consider,  `list` is a built in type, and you should not assign values to it.

Comment: You suggest that it might fail in certain cases depending on the property type. Could you please give some pointers or elaborate ?

Comment: Came across a specific issue when someone in groups/or SO, but can't find it now.  It was a weird corner case in db or ndb from memory.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have used NDB populate () for a similar purpose.